# Why does my toilet keeps blocking and then spill out of the drain outside?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drainage

Recently out toilet has started to repeatedly block. First thing we tried was the warm water method, which worked at first.

When that stopped working, and problem came back, we used caustic soda. This solution worked for a good couple of weeks, but the problem has again come back.

This morning, as I was clearing the toilet is preparation to use the the caustic soda techniques, I noticed a glugging coming from outside the bathroom. I went outside, to see my dirty toilet water being spilled over the patio. An unpleasant site so early in the morning, I think you'll agree.

Other symptoms that may help someone diagnose are that the all the waste pipes, from the kitchen and bathroom, seem to make the toilet glug at times, and this is usually a sign that the toilet is about to start slowing down.

Any ideas on what the problem is or what I can do about it? Should I use caustic soda on the outside drain?

Comment: The water that's spilling across your patio: is it coming out of your outside drain?  If not, where is it coming from?  Are you on a public sewer or a septic system?

Comment: It is coming from my drain, but only when after I clear the blockage in the toilet. If the toilet is going slowly, then the drain overflows. If the toilet is fine, the drain is fine.

Comment: When the toilet is slow, is everything else slow too?

Comment: is the septic tank full or clogged? do you have a septic tank?

Comment: @Mike Powell, not sure. Currently, it's not slow, so I can't test. I'll be sure to investigate.

Comment: @Joel Spolsky, don't have one, I don't think.

Comment: "glug glug glug" sounds like no air behind water. Have you checked the vents on the roof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first step should be to try to divine where in (or outside of) your house the blockage is.  If your outside drain is overflowing you know the blockage is downstream of that, so if that drain is teed off the main waste line coming out of your house, you know you've got a block between the drain and the sewer or septic tank.  If that's the case the most likely culprit is tree roots growing into the pipe, a problem that's not uncommon if your pipe is old and made of clay.  If your house is newer you may find a cleanout port outside you can snake to try to clear any blockage.

If the outside drain is plumbed into your basement or crawlspace then you should look for cleanout ports down there too.  However if all the drains in your house work slowly at the same time, then your problem is likely still outside the house.

Given the seeming interconnectedness of your issues, my gut tells me you've got a blockage that's outside the house, and it's affecting everything.  Your toilet is probably stopping up because of the low water flow -- if the liquid's not flowing out of the toilet quickly enough there's not enough force to effectively push the solids out, and you get a block.

Answer (score 7):

If you have waste water from the toilet spilling across your patio, you need professional help as soon as possible.

Comment: While it's possible this is true, it's not exactly a helpful answer  on a site intented to give DIY info.

Comment: @Mike Powell: So, I assume you gave the downvote? Some things are really not DIY projects, and this sounds like one that is not.

Comment: I did downvote it -- as I said in my comment it's not a helpful answer.  What's not DIY to you might very well be totally within the capabilities of someone else.

Comment: I agree that DIY to one person may not be to another. However, I think some things are beyond DIY. When you have raw sewage flowing across your patio, it is not the time to learn some plumbing.

Comment: I agree with Mike here, I consider myself to be an intelligent, capable person. If I am in too deep, I know when to quit, but that said if I understand the problem better, I can make an informed decision on whether or not to call the pros.

Comment: The OP doesn't know if he has sewer or septic, and I'm being downvoted for suggesting he call a professional?

Comment: The OP wants to learn. This answer tells them - "Don't bother learning, you can't do so." Instead, an answer than helps to explain and understand is consistent with the aims of this site, and is preferred to an answer that provides no understanding at all.

Comment: I'm all for learning. Look at it as learning when to call a professional. The point is, in some situations you need to get it fixed and THEN learn about it. He says he has raw sewage flowing across his patio...that is not something you take your time learning about!

Comment: Nothing wrong with Fuzz learning on his "PooPoo Patio", so long as he's willing.  On electrical DIY forums, the usual response made to those who sound like they are even mildly unsure of themselves is "Stop what you're doing right this second and call a professional, you idiot."  Plumbing most likely isn't going to burn a house down or kill anyone, but still, at some point, the "Call a Professional" advice has to be respected.  Of course, others can give a "DIY" answer, but part of doing successful work is knowing when you need to call someone else in to help and should be respected.

Comment: Plumbing has a risk of contaminating public water supplies with fecal matter. You don't want to be responsible for getting an entire block sick (or potentially dead). If this becomes a possibility, that's a good flag for when you should stop DIYing and call in a professional.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to rent a fiber optic pipe camera. I've actually seen them at the local home store, but at several hundred dollars, they aren't super affordable. Try snaking this camera in at the toilet, or at the drain

Comment: you might want to check plumbers who advertize free video checks, if you agree to get blockage repaired byu them.