# What is the "warm water method" of clearing a clogged toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, blockage

In [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/why-does-my-toilet-keeps-blocking-and-then-spill-out-of-the-drain-outside) the OP mentioned that, when having problems with blocked toilet, as his first attempt he tried *warm water method*.

I would like to ask:

> - What is *warm water method*? For which purposes and in what situations can it be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using warm (should be very hot water) to break up plumbing blockages.  Works for minor issues.  You would simply dump hot water into the drain (or toilet) and let the heated water try to affect the material blocking the pipe.

Comment: If the toilet is sealed with a wax ring, excessively hot water can melt the wax enough to leak.

Comment: That is a great point.  I have actually never used hot water in a toilet.  Wonder if it has negative impact elsewhere?

Comment: I was just answering the question.  I also have never used hot water in a toilet - since the clog is usually relatively close to the surface... Have used a stick!